# How can I see the email addresses of other users on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, private-messaging

Often I ask some question and someone provides very useful answers. So when I ask a similar question, I want to have that person answer it. Or I have an additional question to discuss with them. But I can never see that person's contact method. How can I contact them?

Comment: It is not appropriate to treat individual StackOverflow members as your private unpaid consultants.

Answer (score 3):

A person's email is not publicly available to you. If he/she chooses to include it in their description manually then you can take it, but otherwise you can't get it.

You could post follow up questions on Stack Overflow, or take it to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) with the user, if he/she agrees.

Comment: One thing to note: If you put an e-mail address into an answer/question, it *will* be removed. It's against (community) policy to do so.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby: Not really. It will be removed, sure, but that's just because mods are proactive in protecting PII which may have accidentally leaked. If the user wants it there, then it won't be spirited away.

Comment: @Manishearth: I always remove e-mail addresses...especially requests for "further contact if you have any questions". Not to mention those fuc.... "send the answer via mail plz" and signatures. I don't see how an e-mail address is valid within a question/answer (if not as example or on-topic "you should send a bug report to here:").

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby: Yes, no problem removing them. However, it's not against community policy (I discussed this in TL)

Comment: @Manishearth: Oh, last time I followed a talk about it it seemed pretty established that nobody wants that (no matter how), but was set via "there's a question and answer on Meta about it"...therefor I called it community policy. My bad.

Comment: Yeah, I've never seen these left around outside of very exceptional circumstances. Pretty sure everyone who can edit hates the sight of 'em.